# SQLite3 Discord py Заносятся в таблицу 40 человек и дальше ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, sqlite3

Подскажите пожалуйста по поводу моей проблемы.
При запуске бота в базу заносятся 40 человек и потом ошибка

```
line 56, in on_ready
    cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO main VALUES ('{member}',{member.id}, 0, 500, 1)")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "mbladeshecallmebladee": syntax error
```

Как я понял - это происходит из-за '{member}', но это вывод имен пользователей.
Сам код:

````
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if cursor.execute(f"SELECT member_id FROM main WHERE member_id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO main VALUES ('{member}',{member.id}, 0, 500, 1)")
                db.commit()
            else:
                pass
    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прошу прощение за беспокойство. Немного покопавшись нашел беду в неправильном формате member. Оставлю код если у кого-то будет схожая проблема.

````
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if cursor.execute(f"SELECT member_id FROM main WHERE member_id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO main VALUES (?, ?, 0, 500, 1)", (str(member), member.id))
                db.commit()
            else:
                pass
    ```
````